# CMake uses too long paths when searching for CUDA compiler on Windows

Tags: windows, visual-studio, cmake, clion, nvcc

I am running `CMake` from under `CLion` and when identifying `CUDA` compiler, it apperently uses too long paths, and fails (according to `CMakeError.log` file):

```
Compiling the CUDA compiler identification source file "CMakeCUDACompilerId.cu" failed.
Compiler: C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v10.2/bin/nvcc.exe 
Build flags: 
Id flags: --keep;--keep-dir;tmp -v

The output was:
1

D:\TESTS\CUDA_CLion\test01\cmake-build-debug\CMakeFiles\3.19.1\CompilerIdCUDA>call "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.28.29333/bin/HostX64/x64/../../../../../../../VC/Auxiliary/Build/vcvars64.bat" 
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2019 Developer Command Prompt v16.8.2
** Copyright (c) 2020 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************
The input line is too long.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
#$ C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.28.29333/bin/HostX64/x64/../../../../../../../VC/Auxiliary/Build/vcvars64.bat
nvcc fatal   : Could not set up the environment for Microsoft Visual Studio using 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.28.29333/bin/HostX64/x64/../../../../../../../VC/Auxiliary/Build/vcvars64.bat'
...
```

The command it runs is (according to `CMake` pane of `CLion`):

```
D:\Apps\CMake\bin\cmake.exe -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug --debug-output -G "CodeBlocks - NMake Makefiles" D:\TESTS\CUDA_CLion\test01
```

If I run this command from CLI, it also fails, but with different error:

```
Compiling the CUDA compiler identification source file "CMakeCUDACompilerId.cu" failed.
Compiler: C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v10.2/bin/nvcc.exe 
Build flags: 
Id flags: --keep;--keep-dir;tmp -v

The output was:
1
nvcc fatal   : Cannot find compiler 'cl.exe' in PATH
```

And finally, if I just run

```
cmake ..
```

from CLI it works: it finds itself Ok with long paths, it finds `cl.exe`, everything.

The question is: how to fix everything OR how to force `CLion` just to use only `CMake` without imagination?

Answer (score 1):

Did your script invoke vcvarsall.bat or vcvars64.bat multiple times?
It could be solved by reduce them

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30046720)